# Conceptual Confusion of CORS policy and Web Browsers

Tags: http, browser

How can browsers see pages that do not send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header?

To see a webpage, a request of some type (e.g. `GET` or `POST`) has to be made. But if the server doesn't allow CORS, how can the browser see it (as the user's computer is a different origin than the server's)?

Why do API calls (from request libraries, e.g. Volley on android) need `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, but not browsers? If I am using shared hosting, does this have something to do with the fact that files are place in `public_html`?

Comment: What dou you mean by "see"? Obviously, that header is only evaluated when the URL requested by the user does not match the URL requested from within another page